# Xampp stop working when loop huge array?

Tags: node.js, xampp

I am wondering why xampp stop working when I am try to run my code:

```
for(var pageNo=1; pageNo<= 10658;pageNo++){
carlistrequest('http://www.carlist.my/car?page_number='+pageNo, function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode ==200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('.listing-content').find('h2.vr38dett-title > a').each(function(i, elem){
            var data={
                link: 'http://www.carlist.my/'+$(elem).attr('href')
            };
            console.log(data);
            //insert urls into DB
            connection.query('INSERT INTO urls SET ?', data, function(err, result){
                if(err) throw err;
            })
        })
    }
})
```

}

I got this error:

> Exception EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 0025B32E.
>   Access violation at address 0065B32E in module-xampp-control.exe. Read
>   of address 00000042.

I don't know what wrong with my code but if I run just 1000 page it works properly. Pls help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP at all.

Comment: apache runs out of memory or a possible memory leak. Try breaking the long array in to smaller arrays.

Comment: Such scripts never should be run under apache or in browser, only hardcore console execution...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have memory issues.

How many of almost 11K pages does the script proceed before throwing an exception?

You're having anonymous function that uses variable of outer scope, that should create closure, I'm not sure if it then frees allocated memory.

Maybe you should somehow check amount of memory used, and if my guess is right, then you should refactor your code.

For example you can get all hrefs by regexp, instead of using selector and each loop.

Also try collecting all hrefs in an array, and then, after parsing finished, insert them all at once - you will make less interactions with database that way.